# Design a recursive questions under HTML + Javascript / AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I have some complex if then statement I would like to show on HTML page and be able to add/remove more conditions, they can be recursive, and the Depth is unlimited.

The expressions are in the following format:

```
Question? Answer A : answer B
```

This is the first simple level, but it can be nested like that:

```
Question A? (Question B? Answer 1: answer 2): (Question C? Answer 3: answer 4)
```

Or more nested like that:

```
Question A? (Question B? (Question D? Answer 5: answer 6): answer 2): (Question C? Answer 3: (Question E? Answer 7: answer 8))
```

I’m looking for a way to build an editor of this expression type:

The editor should support the following operations:

1. Add question
2. Add answers
3. Edit question / answers
4. Be able to get expression from server and to show it on UI
5. Generate expression from the UI to send to server
   I was thinking much about how to build it, if any of you can give some inputs about how to approach this situation it be much appreciated.

Comment: My two cents: you might want to look at recursive directives, then feed the directive with a node of your composite structure.

Comment: @Sphaso not sure how to represent it, do you have a simple example of what you mean?

Comment: I'm thinking about having a directive that shows Q+A and inside that the same directive getting the child (children?). From a quick google search it seems possible.